# Use the transformation $x=u^2-v^2$, $y=2uv$ to evaluate the integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, transformation

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\sqrt{1-x}} \! \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Here's where I'm at:

$J(x,y)=4u^2+4v^2$

Substituting $x$ and $y$ into the integral: $\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^2+4u^2v^2} \rightarrow u^2+v^2$

So now our new integral is $\int \int (u^2+v^2)(4u^2+4v^2)$

How do I find the order of integration and bounds for the new integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the given double integral is of the form:
$$
\iint\limits_R f(x,y) \, dA
$$
where the boundary of $R$ consists of the following $3$ curves:
\begin{align*}
R_1&:~~ y = 0 &\text{where }0 \leq x \leq 1\\
R_2&:~~ y = 2\sqrt{1 - x} &\text{where }0 \leq x \leq 1\\
R_3&:~~ x = 0 &\text{where }0 \leq y \leq 2\\
\end{align*}
Now since $x,y \geq 0$ on $R$, observe that:
$$\begin{cases}
u^2 + v^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
u^2 - v^2 = x
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + x}{2}} \\
v = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - x}{2}}
\end{cases}$$
Hence, the boundary of the region $S$ that maps to $R$ (via the given transformation) is defined by the following $3$ curves:
\begin{align*}
S_1&:~~ v = 0 &\text{where }0 \leq u \leq 1\\
S_2&:~~ u = 1 &\text{where }0 \leq v \leq 1\\
S_3&:~~ v = u &\text{where }0 \leq u \leq 1\\
\end{align*}
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. So the order of integration will be $du, dv$ and $du$ going from $0-1$ and $dv$ going from $0-1$?

Comment: Try drawing $S_1, S_2, S_3$ in the $uv$-plane. They form a triangle. What you described was a unit square.

Comment: Ah I think I see it, $du$ from $v$ to $1$ and $dv$ from $0$ to $1$. In that order of integration

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Alternatively, you could switch the order of integration to get:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^u 4(u^2 + v^2)^2 \, dv \, du
$$

Comment: In this case it is also possible to take the triangle in the third quadrant. 
If you take that triangle, you integrate from -1 to 0 in terms of u and from u to 0 in terms of v in that order (or you can switch order). These two areas (triangle in first q and third quadrant) point to the same area in the xy-plane in the very same orientation. That is because switching both u and v's signs at the same time fixes the Jacobian, the x-coord and the y-coord.